# AutoHotKey - Is it possible to get the list of active windows and show it in grid form?

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to simulate a MAC feature which shows the list of active windows when we move the mouse sideways ? 
Also is there is a possiblity to toggle between windows with same title ? like if i have 2-3 chrome open . can i toggle betwen them ?

Comment: That feature in MacOSX is called Exposé.

Answer (score 1):

There are several Expose scripts on the Autohotkey forums:

http://www.google.com/search?q=expose+site:www.autohotkey.com

Answer (score 0):

Using a Windows OS? Try **[VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html)**.

[image]

> Now you can cycle through your open documents as easily as you do with your open applications, using Alt + ` (grave accent or backtick) – just like on Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks ! But i was hoping to write a script for the same , don't want to install yet another application :)

Comment: I'm actually looking for a replacement for program like http://insentient.net/index.html in AHK itself

Comment: @MNH: I think you are overestimating what can be done with AutoHotKey.